# select2 dropdown overlapping on remodal

Tags: jquery, css, z-index, jquery-select2, remodal

When I try to use select2 and [remodal](http://vodkabears.github.io/remodal/) together, select2 dropdown is overlapping on remodal frame. I tried to change z-index of both but I failed to make it work. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been dealing with wrong class of select2. I've solved my problem with this code:

```css
.select2-container{
    z-index:1000 !important;
}
```